# Python Django Invalid block tag: 'endfor' within a simple template

Tags: python, django, templatetags, templatetag

I am new to django&python.
Using python 3.4.2 and django 1.8.
Trying to display a list of products and encountered an error:

> "Exception Type:  TemplateSyntaxError
>
> Exception Value:   Invalid block tag: 'endfor'
>
> Exception Location: myvirtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py in
> invalid_block_tag, line 395"

Can't figure out what's wrong. Found few related questions on stackoverflow but they did't help.

Give me a hint, please. Thanks in advance.

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product

def list_items(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'catalog/list_item.html', {'products': products})
```

list_item.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% block title %}some title{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
            {% for product in products %)
            {{ product }}
            {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S Without   content, {% block title %} renders with no errors.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo:

`{% for product in products %)`

and it should be

`{% for product in products %}`

see difference in bracket `}` not `)`

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your template:

```
{% for product in products %)
```

should be:

```
{% for product in products %}
```